# Remove v-on:click event from an element when it's clicked on

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

How do I remove the v-on:click event from a div when I click on it.

```
<div id="five" v-on:click="setIcon"></div>
```

I want the setIcon click event to be removed immediately I click on this element. I have several other elements that I want to behave this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`.once` event modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers).

```
<div id="five" v-on:click.once="setIcon"></div>
```